# problem with converting NSData to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hi 
I have a problem with converting NSData to NSArray

my code is:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

can any one help me to do it.

Comment: And what might this problem you are having be?

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Comment: Are you sure that buf has a content representing an NSArray? how do you get your `buf`? What is its content?

Comment: please post more of your code or try debugging your app. You can try NSZombie environmetn variable to find the actual crash.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what is inside your byte buffer. This code works for a simple buffer of character bytes.

Try:

```
char buf[]="123456";
NSData *bufObj=[NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)buf length:sizeof buf];
if(bufObj==nil)
    NSLog(@"failed to create obj");
else {
    NSMutableArray *marr=[NSMutableArray array];
    [marr addObject:bufObj];
    NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObject:bufObj];

    NSLog(@"test:\n\tbufObj: %@\n\tmarr: %@\n\tarr: %@",bufObj,marr,arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `+[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:]` to convert the data, then check if the result `-isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]`.

It will work :)